# how to find elements of a factor group, the index and if it is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

2. We know that a subgroup H of an abelian group G is normal because for any a∈G,  aH={ah:h∈H}={ha:h∈H}=Ha. Thus, by Corollary 14.5 of the textbook, the set of all cosets (no matter whether left or right) of a normal subgroup under the coset multiplication is a group G/H, called a factor group of G by H.Based on the these arguments, answer the following:

(a) Find all elements of the factor group ℤ/4ℤ.

(b) Find the index of ℤ by 4ℤ, that is, (ℤ:4ℤ).

(c) Is ℤ/4ℤ cyclic and why?

I really am lost on this one and don't know where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I mean, can you give us a little more?  Do you know what $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is / how it is defined?

Comment: i know that Zv(4) = Z/4Z (that is, the set { 0, 1, 2, 3 } with addition modulo 4), and its subgroup { 0, 2 } . The quotient group Z4/{ 0, 2 } is { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 3 } } . This is a group with identity element { 0, 2 } , and group operations such as { 0, 2 } + { 1, 3 } = { 1, 3}. Both the subgroup { 0, 2 } and the quotient group { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 3 } } are isomorphic with Zv(2).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $H \trianglelefteq G$, and $x+H,y+H \in G/H$, then $x+H = y+H \Leftrightarrow x-y \in H$ (using additive notation).

Two elements $n+\mathbb{Z}, m+\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ are equal iff $n-m \in 4\mathbb{Z}$, that is, $4 \mid n-m$ or equivalenty $n \equiv m\ \text{mod}\ 4$, thus, the elements of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ are the congruence classes $\text{mod}\ 4$. This also tells you the index.

What can you say about the structure of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$? **Hint:** $1+1+1+1 \equiv 0 \ \text{mod}\ 4$.

Comment: so i can say that the structure is cyclic?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $4\mathbb{Z}$, this is the factor group they are referring to.
So $\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$ under addition, and

$4\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,...\}$ also under addition.

Can you deduce the elements, index, and whether or not the factor group is cyclic from here?

By way of example, to find the cosets, begin with the group $4\mathbb{Z}$ above, and then choose an element not in it from $\mathbb{Z}$ (I choose $1$) and then add it into every element of $4\mathbb{Z}$.

$1+\{...,-8,-4,0,4,8,...\}=\{...,-7,-3,1,5,9,...\}=[1]$

where $[1]$ denotes the equivalence class, modulo $4$, containing $1$. Do the same with $2$ and $3$ and then check that every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is in either $[0]=4\mathbb{Z}$, $[1]$, $[2]$, or $[3]$.

Comment: i dont think so...

Comment: Do you know how to find the cosets?

Comment: when you pick a number in the set and multiply it?

Comment: No, that's what you do to construct the subgroup generated by the given element. To find the cosets, you start with the given subgroup (which in the context of factor groups is always normal), and then choose an element of the whole group not in the given subgroup, and multiply it to each element of the given subgroup (in the case of normal subgroups, order does not matter, but it does for subgroups that aren't normal). This constructs a coset, repeat this procedure until all elements of the whole group each belong to a coset you've found.

Comment: so i will be multiplying Z by 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: See my edit for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: ok so 2+{...-8, -4, 0, 4, 8...} = {...-6, -2, 2, 6, 10...}={2}. 3+{...-8, -4, 0, 4, 8...} = {...-5, -1, 3, 7, 11...}={3}. these are the elements of the group?

Comment: Yes, those are the cosets of $H$ in $G$, and since $H$ is normal in $G$, they form a group under coset multiplication (by corollary 14.5 in your book). That group is the factor group, you may recognize it better if you compare it to $\mathbb{Z}_4=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with operation begin addition mod 4, $\oplus_4$. (They are actually isomorphic groups, i.e. have the same structure).